# How to prevent the horizontal scroll bar from being scrolled?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the horizontal scroll bar hidden so that the user cannot scroll . I have read somewhere that my body tag should contain a width of 100% and to set overflow-x:hidden but the following code but I can still scroll a bit on my mobile media query as shown below:

```
html, body {
   background-color: silver;
   height: 400%;
   width: 100%;
   overflow-x:hidden;

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkAiV.jpg)

Comment: Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll

Comment: I have looked at that page but the only difference is the used of webkit but that is only for IE

Comment: Could you share your whole HTML file?

Comment: Do you need my whole css or the main index.php file?

Comment: because it doesn't look correct only for my mobile media query

Comment: I'm going to post an example for you.

Comment: if my answer didn't help you, please provide your HTML and CSS so I can look at it in details.

Answer (score 0):

Check the example below, I've set the div width to be higher than my window and in the body tag, I remove the scroll using an **overflow-x: hidden**.

Since I don't have access to your source I can't help much.

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="scroll">
   <p>Hi</p>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
    body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.scroll {
    min-height:800px;
    min-width: 1000px;
}
```

Working example: [FiddleJs Example](https://jsfiddle.net/se0wbp4o/), note that if you remove the overflow-y the horizontal bar will show up. Maybe you're overwriting the overflow, try to mark it as:

**overflow-y: hidden !important**

Or open your console and debug in there.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work.... I think there is too much code to add here... Can I post my live website and you can check it on your mobile?

Comment: Yes, go ahead. I'll format your post once we're done in order to help further users.

Comment: I am just afraid that some people might register on my site as it is not readied yet

Comment: the thing is that for my mobile version, the user can still scroll to the right a tiny bit

Comment: can you create a div and put all the content inside this div and then do an inline: overflow-x: hidden just to test it. Without the code, I can't debug it.

Comment: I have already done that and it still doesn't work...I know that when viewing on the mobile phones on most site, I can't scroll to the right...

Comment: I got it to work because I was using the wrong meta tag for media query... Must I include this on every single page or just my main index.php?